# Cannot assign to because it's a method group, when converting from VB.NET to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

Here is the code:

```
public abstract class OSHelper
{
    public static bool IsAppAlreadyRunning()
    {
        IsAppAlreadyRunning = false;

        try
        {
            // Current Running Process (this launched app)
            string currentRunningProcessName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

            // Get ALL Running Processes
            Process[] allRunningProcessNames = Process.GetProcessesByName(currentRunningProcessName);

            if (allRunningProcessNames.Length > 1)
                IsAppAlreadyRunning = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log.Write(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Fails when I try to assign false to `IsAppAlreadyRunning`?

This was converted VB.NET code converted to C# ... works great in VB.NET but C# seems to have a problem with it?  In VB.NET this is basically a class that doesn't require an instance in order to access it's methods.

What am I missing? Or is this just something C# doesn't support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VB.NET returns values from methods by assigning the value to the method name.

C# doesn't work like that. Use a `return` statement instead.

```cs
public static bool IsAppAlreadyRunning()
{
    try
    {
        // Current Running Process (this launched app)
        string currentRunningProcessName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

        // Get ALL Running Processes
        Process[] allRunningProcessNames = Process.GetProcessesByName(currentRunningProcessName);

        if (allRunningProcessNames.Length > 1)
            return true;
        // Or replace above 2 lines with
        //    return allRunningProcessNames.Length > 1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log.Write(ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IsAppAlreadyRunning` is a function in the C# code so you cannot assign to it. Try this:

```
public static bool IsAppAlreadyRunning()
{
    bool retVal = false;

    try
    {
        // Current Running Process (this launched app)
        string currentRunningProcessName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

        // Get ALL Running Processes
        Process[] allRunningProcessNames = Process.GetProcessesByName(currentRunningProcessName);

        if (allRunningProcessNames.Length > 1)
        {
            retVal = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log.Write(ex);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Method and variable can't share a name. Rename it to something else.
2. You need to declare your variable, i.e. bool IsAppAlreadyRunningVar = false;
3. You need to make sure that you return value (bool) from every code path. What happens if this condition `if (allRunningProcessNames.Length > 1)` fails?

Comment: Regarding to #1, that is the vb.net way of assigning a return value in a function.

Comment: I didn't know that

Comment: @Cleptus: That is *one* VB way of assigning a return value - another is 'Return' just like in the 'normal' languages.  VB always has to have an offbeat option available.

Comment: @Dave Doknjas: Why is that "offbeat" since one has defined a function that must return something?  Why not be able to use that allocation since it's already been declared?

Comment: @SimHorizon: Because 'return' is used by nearly all languages? Why not use 'Return' in VB (since it works fine) ?

Comment: @Dave Doknjas: Because you can't do anything after a return, what if I have additional logic that manages the bool IsAppAlreadyRunning?  return exits the method, no other  opportunity to use the already allocated bool.

Comment: @SimHorizon: The more you immerse yourself in the weirder aspects of VB, the harder it will be to adapt to other languages. If the method logic is not ready to return something, then don't return something - 'Return' works just like in other languages. VB 'allocates' all kinds of nonsense - you're not wasting anything by not using it.

Comment: @Dave Doknjas: Sorry but you aren't really making much sense, C# function has a return value, it's allocated by definition otherwise use void.  What is "weird" (more accurate is inefficient) is that C# can't operate on the allocation other than with "return" which is changes logic flow also.  Sorry, but that is a "weird" design decision.  BTW, VB has a "return" statement also ... I have no idea why C# language can't use the address it's allocated already by function definition ... that is truly "weird".

Answer (score 0):

The name of the method is **IsAppAlreadyRunning**. You cannot assign true/false to it.

I guess you want to determine if there are active processes with the indicated process name.

Try this:

```
public abstract class OSHelper
{
    public static bool IsAppAlreadyRunning()
    {
        try
        {
            // Current Running Process (this launched app)
            string currentRunningProcessName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

            // Get ALL Running Processes
            Process[] allRunningProcessNames = Process.GetProcessesByName(currentRunningProcessName);

            return allRunningProcessNames.Length > 1;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log.Write(ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```